# MSSQL - trigger to disable old records beeing updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have large system coded in PHP (ages ago) - it runs queries on **MSSQL** database. What I need is to create a trigger on a database level, that will disable any update statement to proceed if the update was going to change the column `f_month` to 99 (ie. contains update [table] set `f_month='99'`) on a row that has `my_date <= [24months before now or older]`. I expect this should be feasible, but have no luck trying to figure out how on my own.. thanks for any suggests, Jan

-------------- working for one row updates, but fails on multiople row update --------------

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_fix
    ON  mytable
    FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    if (select f_month from inserted)=99 and (select x_date from mytable where data_id in((select data_id from inserted)))<=DateAdd(yy,-2,GetDate())
    BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Cannot update old records',16,1)
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
          RETURN;
    END
END 
GO
```

The above shown solution works just fine if one row is beeing updated, however it does not work for updates affecting multiple row..and that is a problem..can anyone help me changing the trigger to work for updates affecting multiple rows? Should examine each row beeing updated separately - so if there is an update of 10 rows where one of them should not be updated - just that one will not be updated, other rows will be updated sucessfully..Is that even possible with a trigger?

Comment: SQL Server triggers execute once per statement, and so this trigger may be working against a set of rows, *some* of which fit your criteria and some of which *don't*. What do you want to do in such a case? Fail the entire statement? Allow valid changes, ignore invalid changes? Something else?

Comment: As Damien says, this is all quite possible using a trigger, but we'll need more of a spec to point you in the right direction. It might be best if you try doing this on your own and change your question to add more details of where you're getting stuck.

Comment: the trigger I created works fine for updates affecting one row, if more rows are affected, the trigger does not work .. tried to change it many ways, but no luck making it work..not sure if it is even possible to work the way I would like to..any suggestes? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Check constraint,that  might also help .